# Linq query with All rule in array

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of images and I want to search for multiple keywords with a BOTH rules

For example if I search for "dancing child" I want to show a list of items with both keywords dancing and child

I implemented a query something like this:

```
List<string> target_keywords = //an array contains Keywords to Lookup 
var RuleAny_results = (from imageItem in images                     
                       select new{ imageItem,
                             Rank =target_keywords.Any(x => imageItem.Title != null && imageItem.Title.ToLower().Contains(x)) ? 5 :
                                   target_keywords.Any(x => imageItem.Name != null && imageItem.Name.ToLower().Contains(x)) ? 4 :                                  
                                0
                         }).OrderByDescending(i => i.Rank);
//exclude results with no match (ie rank=0 ) and get a Distinct set  of items
_searchResult = (from item in RuleAny_results
             where item.Rank != 0
             select item.imageItem).Distinct().ToList();
```

But this will return results with any of the items in the `target_keywords`, e.g. if I search for "dancing child" above code returns list of items with any of the keywords dancing or child. But I want the list with Both dancing and child keywords only

So how can I convert the query so that it fetch all records that contains BOTH keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Linq.Enumerable::All is what you want.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

struct ImageItem {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

bool Contains(string toSearch, string x) {
    return toSearch != null && toSearch.ToLower().Contains(x);
}

IEnumerable<ImageItem> FilterItems(IEnumerable<string> targetKeywords, IEnumerable<ImageItem> items) {
    return items.Where(item => targetKeywords.All(x => Contains(item.Name, x) || Contains(item.Title, x)));

}
```

Comment: i tried with All  BUt the problem is If title Contains  "dancing" and Name contains "child" then "dancing child"keywords return 0 results with All

Comment: What do you want it to return?!

Comment: I want to return list of items with both  keywords [ The keywords can be in Title or in Name property ]   Like if Title contains "dancing" and  Name contains "child" Then i want to return that item as a result for keyword "dancing child"

Comment: So what's the point in the rank at all then? Why can't you just use Where like this?

`images.Where(imageItem => targetKeywords.All(x => Contains(item.Title, x) || Contains(item.Name, x))`

Comment: Its helpful , BUt i ends up with a solution of  Find containSearch  List for every keywords and extracting and Intersection of all as the resultant list

Comment: @JMat really? Why do you say that?

Comment: I dont know the code is not returning the items for me in a scenario where i have tags as car , bergen city  And i search for  "car bergen " but i am not getting the entry

Answer (score -1):

Try this:--

you have to just replace **Any** keyword in syntax with **All**
And one more rank condition for all keyword in both fields

Replace `target_keywords.Any(` with `target_keywords.All(`

```
List<string> target_keywords = //an array contains Keywords to Lookup 
var RuleAny_results = (from imageItem in images                     
                       select new{ imageItem,
                             Rank =target_keywords.Any(x => imageItem.Title != null && imageItem.Title.ToLower().Contains(x)) ? 5 :
                                   target_keywords.All(x => imageItem.Name != null && imageItem.Name.ToLower().Contains(x)) ? 4 :   
                                   target_keywords.All(x => (imageItem.Name != null && imageItem.Name.ToLower().Contains(x)) || imageItem.Title != null && imageItem.Title.ToLower().Contains(x)) ? 3 :                                
                                0
                         }).OrderByDescending(i => i.Rank);
//exclude results with no match (ie rank=0 ) and get a Distinct set  of items
_searchResult = (from item in RuleAny_results
             where item.Rank != 0
             select item.imageItem).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: I see you have changed only one of the Any to All, is this deliberate?

This will allow through an ImageItem with a title of "Dancing" and a null name, which is not what the OP wants.

Of course you could change the other Any to All, but that would not allow through something with "Dancing" as title and "Girl" as Name, which is also not what the op wants.

Comment: It will still allow through an item with a title of "Dancing" and a null name

Answer (score -3):

```
class ImageDemo
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    static void TestCode()
    {
        List<string> target_keywords = new List<string>(){"dancing","child"};
        List<ImageDemo> images = new List<ImageDemo>()
        {  
            new ImageDemo{Title = "dancing"}  ,
             new ImageDemo{Name = "child"}  ,
             new ImageDemo{Title = "child", Name="dancing"}  ,
             new ImageDemo{Title = "dancing", Name="child"}  ,
             new ImageDemo{Name="dancing child"} ,
             new ImageDemo{Title="dancing child"} 
        };
        var searchFuncs = target_keywords.Select(x =>
        {
            Func<ImageDemo, bool> func = (img) =>
            {
                return (img.Title ?? string.Empty).Contains(x) || (img.Name ?? string.Empty).Contains(x);
            };
            return func;
        });
        IEnumerable<ImageDemo> result = images;
        foreach (var func in searchFuncs)
        {
            result = result.Where(x => func(x));
        }
        foreach (var img in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Title:{0}  Name:{1}", img.Title, img.Name));
        }
    }
```

is it the right code you want now?

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the problem of searching over both the name and title of the image.

Comment: That still doesn't really solve the problem. If the title and name are both present, you're only searching in the title, which doesn't help with the OP's example where you have

`new ImageDemo { Name = "Dancing", Title = "Child"}`

Comment: it means u need all keywords in both title and name?